# How to check for equal property values in 2 Array of Objects in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

Let's say I have 2 arrays:

```
const array_1 = [ { id: 1, sex: 'M' }, { id: 2, sex: 'F' }, { id: 3, sex: 'M' } ]
const array_2 = [ { id: 12, age:1 }, { id: 22, age: 4 }, { id: 3, age: 2 } ]
```

And I want to check if there's a value in `array_1` that is also in `array_2`. I can do something like:

```
array_1.forEach((el_1) => {
  array_2.forEach((el_2, i) => {
    if(el_1.id === el_2.id) alert(i);
  })
})
```

Or using ECMAScript 2015 findIndex method:

```
array_1.forEach((el_1) => {
  const i = array_2.findIndex(x => x.id === el_1.id)
  if(i >= 0) alert(i);
})
```

If you want to check the output: https://jsfiddle.net/v7bjnpa7/1/

Normally that would work, but is there a cleaner way to do this? By clean I mean a better way that would not affect the performance? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you show what is the expected output after checking this logic?

Comment: @palaѕн https://jsfiddle.net/v7bjnpa7/

Comment: Since you mentioned `es6`. `array_1.forEach((el) => { return array_2.includes(el); })`

Comment: @nilobarp can't use includes because of different properties in the array

Comment: ```alert (array_2.findIndex(e2 => {return array_1.some(e1 => e1.id == e2.id)}))```

https://jsfiddle.net/y0f6vwcf/

Comment: What exactly do you want to do once the objects have been found?

Comment: @RogersSampaio I like that code

Comment: @FewFlyBy let me know if it is the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(array_1.find( e1 => array_2.find( e2 => e1.id == e2.id))) {
    alert('found');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You Can user **Underscore js** [http://underscorejs.org/][1]

There you will have methods to compare, intersection and lot more.

**try it**

or

```
const array_1 = [ { id: 1, sex: 'M' }, { id: 2, sex: 'F' }, { id: 3, sex: 'M' } ];
const array_2 = [ { id: 12, age:1 }, { id: 22, age: 4 }, { id: 3, age: 2 } ];

array_1.forEach(function(item)
{

    array_2.forEach(function (item2) {

        if(item.id==item2.id)
        {
            console.log(item,item2)
        }
    });


});
```